# how can i split the particular data from a string?

Tags: android, string

I am getting the lat-long from the current location now how can i split the only lat long values from a given string :-
"lat/lng: (23.0326542,72.5279697)"? i want to get only "23.0326542,72.5279697".

Comment: there are at least 3 (clean) ways of doing that, which one did you try?

Comment: Have you [searched for this at all?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+split+string+comma)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   String line = "lat/lng: (23.0326542,72.5279697)";
        String[] array = line.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)");
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(array[i]);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(1));
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be taking the substring of this string, from the beginning of the value you need, to the length of the string.